# PHP. Safely writing to a file

Tags: php, flock

I would like to know if the below code was written correctly. I'm trying to write a safe critical part which writes inside a file and tries to anticipate anything that could go wrong.

Is there anything I should be on the lookout ? I mean, I wrote the try-catch statement in case something goes wrong in the flock so it manages to close the file and release the lock. Is there anything else one should be cautious about?

```
        /*
         * Write to file
         */
        if ( file_exists($sPath) )
        {
            //CRITICAL PART (start)
            $oFile = fopen($sPath, "a");

            //If could not open file then just return
            if ( $oFile == false ) return;

            try{
                //Acquire lock
                if ( flock($oFile, LOCK_EX) )
                {
                    //Append a new line
                    fwrite($oFile, "\n"."sometext");
                }
            }catch(Exception $e){
                //Release lock before exiting
                fclose($oFile);
                return;
            }
            //Release lock
            fclose($oFile);
            //CRITICAL PART (end)
        }
```

Comment: Both [`flock`](http://php.net/flock) and [`fwrite`](http://php.net/fwrite) do not throw any exceptions, therefore the try/catch block does not make any sense to me.

Comment: oh...you are right. Good observation hakre, thanks.

Comment: Also Stackoverflow works best if you ask a concrete programming question about a concrete problem. Questions like *"Is there anything I should be on the lookout ?"* + here is my code do not work out well in a Q&A format.

Comment: @AndreiBogdan Even if they were throwing exceptions, you should use `finally` block to release resources. [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 2):

```
file_put_contents($sPath,"\n"."sometext", FILE_APPEND);
```

I believe that locking is not required for appending. Filesystem will handle it all right.
However, I could be wrong

Comment: Most file systems support atomic append except NFS, whereas `flock()` should be supported on it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Native php functions don't throw exceptions (at least the vast majority don't do... newer functions in OOP native code **do** throw exceptions, you know `DateTime` and the like...), so your `try/catch` is useless there. You would need to check the return value of all functions and check that it is not `false`. Other than that, I think you are managing it quite well.

As a side note, file locking is advisory in linux (I don't know in other platforms), so you are not acquiring a real lock on the file. I mean, other processes may modify/overwrite/delete the file you are "locking".

Comment: Wrong. That never is not a never in PHP. Even it's common, IIRC there are exceptions to that rule.

Comment: @hakre what rule do yo mean?

Comment: The "rule" you formulated that core functions never throw exceptions.

Comment: ah ok... editing it...

Answer (score 1):

Since the `fopen` function returns a file pointer resource on success, or `FALSE` on error, you can use triple comparison ===, i.e.:

```
if ( $oFile === false ) return;
```